# Birt Upgradation - from Birt 3.2.20 to Birt 4.3.2 (in XML Source tab of Report Design page how to change verion number to latest version)

Tags: jakarta-ee, birt

from Birt Migration guide I came to know that by replacing old jar files(belongs to birt) from my Web Application(**deployed in Tomcat7**) with new jar files in latest version **birt-runtime-osgi-4_3_2**                                                                            I did the same and it's working fine. and Reports are generating.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 But **in design page**, in **XML Source** tab                                                               `<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.20" id="1">`

In this line if I change version to 4.3.2 instead of 3.2.20 Report is not generating, while generating report it shows bellow exception

```
    There is no report design object available.

org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: There is no report design object available.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.__init(ViewerAttributeBean.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseAttributeBean.init(BaseAttributeBean.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.ViewerAttributeBean.<init>(ViewerAttributeBean.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.__init(BirtContext.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BaseContext.<init>(BaseContext.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.context.BirtContext.<init>(BirtContext.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__getContext(ViewerServlet.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:151)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

if I change it to 3.2.20 again then it's working. 
How to change it to latest Birt version 4.3.2.
                                               Is my application is upgraded to latest version of BIRT or not. If it is upgraded why it is not taking version number 4.3.2 in XMX Source tab of all report design pages. Pls help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of reportEngine and version of report designs are two completely different things.

By upgrading JAR's with runtime to 4.3.2, your report engine is now correctly upgraded on Tomcat. However your reports have been developed with an Eclipse designer 3.2.20, generally there is a good backward compatibility, it should be fine.

You should never try to update manually the version number of reports, Eclipse handles this automatically. If you still want to upgrade reports, open them with an Eclipse designer 4.3.2 and they will be converted when they are saved.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Edit with new version of Birt designer, then open this file with text editor and change this labels to your version.

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.17" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.3.2.v20140211-1400 Build &lt;4.3.2.v20140218-1056></property>
```